# Android: Camera.Parameters.setRotation() unexpected result in Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, parameters, camera, rotation, image

Without calling `parameters.setRotation()`, the direction of the picture saved by pictureCallback is not same as preview on screen, so I add the line `parameters.setRotation(90)` for test, after adding this line, the direction of the saved picture is correct, and without any problem in my Nexus One.

In Galaxy Nexus, the direction is also correct, but everything in the picture is thin and tall than what they are, and I notice that the result is inconsistency, sometimes thinner and taller than other times even the picture size passed to `parameters.setPictureSize()` is not changed. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?

I ask some of my friends to test the code lately, the problem seems only appears in Galaxy Nexus.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewSize(previewWidth, previewHeight);
parameters.setPictureSize(pictureWidth, pictureHeight);
parameters.setRotation(90);
camera.setParameters(parameters);
camera.startPreview();
camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, null, pictureCallback);
```

Here is the code of takePicture() in PictureCallback:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    errorMessage = null;//reset to null first
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: "+e.getMessage());
        errorMessage = "Failed to create media file, storage not available!";
    }else{
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            errorMessage = "Failed to create media file!";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
            errorMessage ="Error while writing media file!";
        }finally{
            try{
                if(fos!=null){
                    fos.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I was implementing my camera application I had to save image orientation manually using ``ExifInterface`` as returned image did not contain correct value.

Comment: What are the values of previewWidth, previewHeight, pictureWidth, pictureHeight on both devices? Does Nexus 1 run GingerBread? Are you holding the device in portrait or landscape orientation?

Comment: harism, I will try to use ExifInterface, thank you.

Comment: Alex, previewWidth, previewHeight, pictureWidth, pictureHeight are the size values returned by Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes() and Camera.Parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes(), they may not same value since different devices support different values, some values are supported both of my devices, even I use the same supported values for test, the result of G Nexus is still incorrect.